# notepad++ regex pattern to find the string

Tags: notepad++

I wanted to highlight/find string till `'-'` character

```
04,035 [1] INFO  - ascf
05,589 [1] INFO  - jtion
07,365 [1] INFO  - dbi
09,563 [1] INFO  - braho
```

what could be the regex pattern to find the string?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match everything up to the "-" character you could use:

```
^.*?-
```

[image]

Here is a great site for testing regexes:

https://regex101.com

Hope this helps. :-)